# Store images of word document in sql database

Tags: sql-server, vba, sql-server-2012, ms-word

I want to store all images of a word document in an sql database. I found several code samples on how to parse the images via the `InlineShapes` collection, which work fine. However, I'm now missing an example on how to store the image in an sql server image column.

Could anyone post an example, which stores the `InlineShape` object in the database. Either using the `command` or `recordset` object?

**Update**: Here is the code

```
Sub SavePictures()

Dim SQL As String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnBon As ADODB.Connection
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

SQL = "Select [ID] ,[Datei] ,[Seite] ,[Bild] from Bilder Where 1=0"

strConn = "working Connection string"

Set cnBon = New ADODB.Connection
cnBon.Open strConn


Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open SQL, cnBon, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText


    For i = 1 To InlineShapes.Count

        If InlineShapes.Item(i).Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then

            RS.AddNew


            RS("Datei") = ActiveDocument.Name
            RS("Seite") = i 
            'This is where I'm stuck. How do I Access the Picture to save it in the Recordset?
            RS("Bild") = InlineShapes.Item(i)

            RS.Update

        End If
    Next i


RS.Close
cnBon.Close

Set RS = Nothing
Set cbbon = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code

```
Sub SavePictures()

Dim SQL As String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnBon As ADODB.Connection
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

SQL = "Select [ID] ,[Datei] ,[Seite] ,[Bild] from Bilder Where 1=0"

strConn = "working Connection string"

Set cnBon = New ADODB.Connection
cnBon.Open strConn


Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open SQL, cnBon, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText


    For i = 1 To InlineShapes.Count

        If InlineShapes.Item(i).Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then

            RS.AddNew


            RS("Datei") = ActiveDocument.Name
            RS("Seite") = i 
            'This is where I'm stuck. How do I Access the Picture to save it in the Recordset?
            RS("Bild") = InlineShapes.Item(i).Range.EnhMetaFileBits

            RS.Update

        End If
    Next i


RS.Close
cnBon.Close

Set RS = Nothing
Set cbbon = Nothing

End Sub
```